# Jquery validation - checking email and username availability from server-side Django

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate the registration form for email and username availability from server-side programmed with Django. I checked this one [jQuery Validation Plugin remote check for password with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365859/jquery-validation-plugin-remote-check-for-password-with-django) but I'm getting 403 forbidden - CSRF verification failed. I tried including csrf token inside the jquery script. But still not working. I've shown the code below for checking email availability.

views.py:

```
def email_check(request):
    response_str="false"
    if request.is_ajax():
        e = request.POST.get("email_address")
        try:
            obj = User.objects.get(email=e)
        except DoesNotExist:
            response_str="true"
    return HttpResponse(response_str)
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^signup/email/check/$', 'registration.views.email_check')
```

signup.html:
https://gist.github.com/2253002

Could anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using django , you dont need JQuery to do all this...User registration should be done through Forms..See this : http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/sep/02/django-tips-user-registration/

Comment: @RamandeepSingh Ajax feature is the must one. So that I'm using jQuery validation plugin.

Comment: "but it's not working". What's not working?

Comment: I'm not getting the indication that the email is already taken for the used email address.

Comment: Try to work out what part is not working. Is the query plugin making an ajax request to the correct url? Is the view returning the correct response?

Comment: url is correct..but I have doubt in sending the response..don't know how to do it.

Comment: From the sound of it, the response doesn't even get sent to the client. If that's the case, you should get have some error from the server. What's the error?

Comment: Use Firebug in Firefox or Web Inspector in Chrome, look into Network tab and find your ajax request. You'll be able to see the response there.

Comment: @ahmoo I'm getting 403 Forbidden - CSRF verification failed

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request

Answer (score 2):

You should send the csrf token in  a cookie named "X-CSRFToken", there is a way to globally enable this behavior with jQuery like this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html').ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
        // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
    }
});
```

Reference the above jquery code in your template to ensure your AJAX POST calls always include the csrf token. For the details, check [this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) from the official doc.